# In Eclipse, how do I set a keyboard shortcut for duplicating DOWNWARD?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I go to keyboard shortcuts, I only have the option to duplicate in general, which apparently is set to upward. (Basically the line you select to duplicate will appear ABOVE what you're duplicating, rather than below, which feels more natural for me.)

[image]

So I was wondering if there was a way to make it so I could duplicate downward instead?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-Alt-Down arrow? (Cmd-Opt-Down for OS X)

Comment: I have that overrode with a system-wide command, so that's a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the shortcut for copy the row downward seems to be *"Copy Lines"* (at least in Eclipse Juno). Just try to change that to whatever you like. Just search "*Lines*" and you should find it.

Another option, which I prefer, is to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>up arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> (which sometimes is used by Windows to flip the screen) system command. I'm very used to the default Eclipse short cut, so this is what I typically do.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'm using a Mac, and I have that keyboard shortcut set system-wide to a window management scheme. As I'm not too attached to the Eclipse one (I really only dupe downward) your help was perfect. Unfriendly choice by the Eclipse team, though. :/